# Best way to check if model returns results in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I'm fairly new to Laravel and looking for the best method for checking whether a model has returned any results or not.

The example below will return `null` if not results are found. Which is perfect if you only ever want the first result.

```
$results = FooBar::where(['col' => 'someVal', 'col3' => 'value'])->first();
```

The example below will return an object regardless of there being any results.

```
$results = FooBar::where(['col' => 'someVal', 'col3' => 'value'])->get();
```

Therefore i'm currently having to do this every time:

```
if($results && count($results)) {
     // then do stuff
}
```

I have methods that call various models and the code looks ugly and inefficient with all of these `count()` functions.

FYI I'm currently using Laravel 5.1 due to our PHP version (not within my control).

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki thanks but this won't work as the result won't be `null`, it will be an object

Comment: `->get()` combined with `if(count($results) != 0)` should be all you need. `count()` works on a Collection the same way it does on an array.

Comment: @TimLewis I clearly haven't got a clue as i'm trying the things suggested but to no avail. I think the issue is with me at this point. I need more experience. Thanks anyway.

Comment: `$results = FooBar::where(['col' => 'someVal', 'col3' => 'value'])->get(); if(count($results) != 0) { // something returned }` shouldn't have any issue, and it's what I use that on a daily basis. Something similar is also suggested in the duplicate, so read that when you can. And don't worry about it, eventually this'll just click. Keep at it.

Comment: [`findOrFail()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You condition is unnecessary too complex, because you cannot do both `->first()` and `->get()`, therefore you do not need to check both conditions as depending on method you called, one will always be in vein. As you noticed, `->first()` can return `null` - so if you call that method, you check result against `null`-  and I'd suggest doing `$result === null` instead of using `is_null()`:

```
if ($result !== null) {
    ...
```

For calling `get()` or in general method returning `Collection`, you will always get it. But it can be empty. In fact, you do not need to know how many results your collection stores. You just need to know if you get at least one, therefore all you need to call is `isEmpty()` on the collection object:

```
if (!$collection->isEmpty()) {
  ...
```

See [docs on Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#introduction)

Comment: Unfortunately `empty()` can't detect the empty collection...

Comment: my bad. I meant `isEmpty()`. Updated the answer

Comment: Unfortunately i'm not dealing with `Collection::`. I'm using `eloquent` https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent

Comment: Eloquent, using `->get()` returns a `Collection`, so yes, you are :P

Comment: Yes, you are. Read docs you linked to :)

Comment: I tried this and it worked for me 
$lead = Lead::where('mobile',$data['mobile'])->first();
if(!$lead) echo "no record";